# Erro Object reference not set to an instance of an object em c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou com problema, quando vou registrar o meu rota ele aparece um erro na hora em que o sistema ira fazer a comparação para ver se o NumCarroId que está no DropDownList é o mesmo que está no banco para pode fazer a alteração.

Erro que me aparece:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

```
Line 28:         public ActionResult Adiciona(RotaModel viewModel)
Line 29:         {
Line 30:             var rotas = ckm.Consulta(viewModel.NumCarroId);
Line 31:             //  Aqui busca todas as rotas deste veículo
```

Meu ViewModel Rota:

```
public class RotaModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Combustivel { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataSaida { get; set; }
    public int AutorId { get; set; }
    public int NumCarroId { get; set; }
    public int Km { get; set; }

    public Rota CriaRota()
    {
        Rota rota = new Rota()
        {
            Id = this.Id,
            Combustivel = this.Combustivel,
            DataSaida = this.DataSaida,
            Km = this.Km
        };
        if (this.AutorId != 0)
        {
            Usuario autor = new Usuario()
            {
                Id = this.AutorId
            };
            rota.Autor = autor;
        }
        if (this.NumCarroId != 0)
        {
            Veiculo numcarroid = new Veiculo()
            {
                NCarro = this.NumCarroId
            };
            rota.NumCarro = numcarroid;
        }
        return rota;
    }

    public RotaModel(Rota r)
    {
        this.Id = r.Id;
        this.DataSaida = r.DataSaida;
        this.Combustivel = r.Combustivel;
        if (r.Autor != null)
        {
            this.AutorId = r.Autor.Id;
        }
        if (r.NumCarro != null)
        {
            this.NumCarroId = r.NumCarro.Id;
        }
    }
    public RotaModel()
    {
    /*
     *construtor vazio para ele assumir como default quando for instanciar  a classe
     */
    }
```

Consulta do NumCarroId:

```
public IList<Rota> Consulta(int NumCarroId)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT NumCarroId FROM Rota";
        IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Rota>();
    }
```

Minha Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Adiciona(RotaModel viewModel)
    {
        var rotas = ckm.Consulta(viewModel.NumCarroId);
        //  Aqui busca todas as rotas deste veículo

        var maiorRota = rotas.OrderByDescending(r => r.Km).FirstOrDefault();
        //  Aqui você tem a última rota cadastrada, considerando a regra geral  

        if (viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
            "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota();
            dao.Adiciona(rota);
            //return View();
            return RedirectToAction("Form");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
            ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
            return View("Form", viewModel);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você retorna no seu método um `IList<Rota>`, porém, a consulta retorna somente um `INT` (NumCarroId). Mude sua query para:

```
string hql = $"SELECT * FROM Rota WHERE NumCarroId = {NumCarroId}";
```

Caso esteja usando c# menor que a versão 6:

```
string hql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Rota WHERE NumCarroId = {0}", NumCarroId);
```

Comment: Fiz oque foi descrito, mas mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: você está usando NHibernate?

Comment: Onde está estourando o erro? Em qual linha?

Comment: uso nhibernate,sim o erro está acontecendo no meu controller na linha 30

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema que estava acontecendo

Comment: Então é no método Consulta. Coloque um breakpoint e me fale em qual lugar desse método Consulta está dando o erro

Comment: ckm estava null? Poste a solução, por favor.

Comment: Fiz isso, o problema que o meu controller não estava importando a classe, provavelmente apago a importação da classe quando fui fazer alguns testes

Answer (score 0):

A importação havia sido apagada quando fui fazer alguns testes no meu controller, arrumei porem constou outro erro na classe que faz a consulta, porem so foi eu fazer com que a consulta pegasse todos os resultados, o controller analisa qual será o necessario.

Controller:

```
public class RotaController : Controller
{
    private RotaDAO dao;
    private ControleKm ckm;
    private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;
    private VeiculoDAO veiculoDAO;

    public RotaController(RotaDAO dao, UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO, VeiculoDAO veiculoDAO, ControleKm ckm)
    {
        this.veiculoDAO = veiculoDAO;
        this.dao = dao;
        this.ckm = ckm; // Essa linha havia sido apagada, por isso estava com erro
        this.usuarioDAO = usuarioDAO;
    }
```

Classe de Consulta:

```
public class ControleKm : Controller
{
    private Rota r;
    private ISession session;
    public ControleKm(ISession session, Rota r)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public IList<Rota> Consulta(int NumCarroId)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT r FROM Rota r";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Rota>();
    }
```